# JQuery-UI Datepicker Bound Lates possible Date to Now?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use [JQuery-Ui Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) like in the following way:

```
    $(".dateElement").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1970:2013"
    });
```

In the above example the  months, year and range are fix. Assume you want the user to insert his birthday. How can I set the lates possible  month to the current month and the latest possible year to the current year?

What I want is to ensure that the user cannot insert a date that is in the future. Howcan I do that=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will limit a datepicker to the current month and year:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
 $(".dateElement").datepicker({ 
     maxDate: new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),
                       currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                       -1) // 1st day of next month minus 1 day
 });
```

However, if you want to limit it to no later than the current date (so days after today in the current month do not apply), you can just do this:

```
 $(".dateElement").datepicker({ 
     maxDate: 0 // 0 days from today
 });
```

API docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 0):

```
maxDate: 0
```

[jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)